# Oauth invalid credentials on creating event in google calendar

Tags: oauth, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, signpost

I am using signpost to   create event in google calendar. After  crossing  all oAuth flow  and trying  to add event  i am getting follow error.

```
"error": {
 "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "authError",
   "message": "Invalid Credentials"
   "locationType": "header",
   "location": "Authorization"
  }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I would double check the Authorization header, mainly the access token type and token you're passing along.

Comment: You can use the google tokeninfo endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<your-token-here> to see if your token is actually valid.